# How to add an element id to the url of the Thymeleaf template in the controller in Spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Application and **Server Side Rendering with Thymeleaf** as Templating language.
A button sends a **get or post request to the controller in Spring**, which puts some message to the view, which is rendered into the HTML file and send back to the client. The message should be optional. Thats why the template must also be able to be called without the message.

Next **i want the client browser to scroll down to the part of the page** where this message is rendered into, which is normally very easy. You would just have to append the id of the element to the url like following example.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/#footer
```

In this example the browser scrolls down to the footer of the page.

Below is what i tried. Unfortunately it doesnt't work like that. Spring/Thymeleaf tries to find a index#messagebox template which can't be found. Hence a Whitelabel Error Page error is thrown/shown.

**Page.html**

```
<section>
    <h2>Form to send request</h2>
    <form action="showmessage" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Click for message">
    </form>
</section>
```

**Controller.java**

```
@GetMapping("showmessage")
public ModelAndView showMessage(){
    return new ModelAndView("index#messagebox",Map.of("optionalmessage","Some message that is optioal"));
}
```

src/main/resources/templates/**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
    <div id="messagebox" th:fragment="message" th:with="optionalmessage=${optionalmessage}">
        <p th:if="${optionalmessage!=null}">[[${optionalmessage}]]</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved with Flashmessages and Redirects. The html basically keeps the same. If the message attribute is set, you render it.

src/main/resources/templates/**index.html**

```
<div th:if="${msg}">
    <div class="message" >
        <p>[[${msg}]]</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The most important changes had to be made in the controller. First a parameter of type **RedirectAttributes** is added to the Controller that handles the request.
If wanted the message is added with the **RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute** function as shown below. Finally a redirect is returned, which contains the needed tag. A second controller is also needed that handles the Get Request of the Redirect with a **Model** as input parameter and returns the needed Template. The **#tag** is simply passed throuhg to the client browser.

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("showMessage")
public String postNotification(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("optinalMessage", "Hello I am an optional message");
    return "redirect:/index#footer";
}
```

```
@GetMapping("index")
public String getIndex(Model model) {
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You add id in URL by using `?id=value`.

And in controller `@RequestMapping("/path/{id}")`
to access that variable `@PathVariable`